# Connect to SQL Server from Python

Tags: python, sql-server

What I have in SQLite at the moment in the JSON configuration file:

```
"db": "sqlite:///\\\\F\\Evaluations\\data\\abc.db"
```

What I want is to connect to a database in SQL Server. How I do that?

`db` is used in the pipeline numerous times in different python files as follows:

```
...
self.db = settings['db']
...
    engine = sa.create_engine( self.db, echo=False)
    conn = engine.connect()
```

Comment: Have you [tried the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/python-sql-driver-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15)? Have you installed the pyodbc driver?

Answer (score 0):

First, try to install pyodbc with the following command:

```
pip install pyodbc
```

Then, you can simply add the MS SQL  URI connection to the JSON config file as follows:

```
"db_mssql":"mssql+pyodbc://username:password@host:port/database"
```

Then, in your python script:

```
self.db = settings['db_mssql']
engine = sa.create_engine( self.db, echo=False)
conn = engine.connect()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are connecting through sqlalchemy. Your connection string for SQL server will need to include more information such as:

- host name/server name
- database name
- credentials (or specify a trusted connection)
- driver name

It will be good to test in a different script first.

```py
import sqlalchemy as db
import pyodbc             # you may need to install pyodbc (or use a different supported driver)

server_name = 'localhost'
database_name = 'AdventureWorks2019'

# directly specify your driver
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

# or use pyodbc to find it
# driver = [x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.endswith(' for SQL Server')]
# driver = driver[0]

# specifying a username/password
engine = db.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://USERNAME:PASSWORD@'+server_name+'/'+database_name+'?driver='+driver)

# or using a trusted connection
# sqlalchemy will add "trusted_connection=yes" if username/password isn't specified
engine = db.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@'+server_name+'/'+database_name+'?driver='+driver)
```

Then your JSON configuration will end up being something like:

```py
"db": "mssql+pyodbc://USERNAME:PASSWORD@localhost/AdventureWorks2019?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"

OR

"db": "mssql+pyodbc://@localhost/AdventureWorks2019?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"
```

Side note, there is an extra parameter to speed up inserts into SQL server, if you find yourself needing it.

```py
db.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://USERNAME:PASSWORD@'+server_name+'/'+database_name+'?driver='+driver, fast_executemany=True)
```

Reference Links:

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html